# Restricting input from two other tables

Tags: mysql, oracle-18c

I'm trying to create the table `CanTeach` but I am getting an error `ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'mydb'.'CanTeach' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed").` Ultimately, I'm trying to create a table of "classes that teacher's can teach" verifying they work for the department that offers the class.

```
CREATE TABLE Department (
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE Person (
    SSN CHAR(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255)
);
CREATE TABLE Professor (
    SSN CHAR(9),
    PRIMARY KEY(SSN),
    FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES Person(SSN)
);
CREATE TABLE WorksFOR (
    SSN CHAR(9),
    Salary float NOT NULL,
    DepName varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT WorksFor_Salary CHECK (Salary>=0),
    CONSTRAINT WorksFor_pk PRIMARY KEY(SSN,DepName),
    CONSTRAINT WorksFor_ssn_fk FOREIGN KEY(SSN) REFERENCES Professor(SSN),
    CONSTRAINT WorksFor_dep_fk FOREIGN KEY(DepName) REFERENCES Department(Name)
);
CREATE TABLE Course (
    CourseDepartment varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CourseNumber varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Course_pk PRIMARY KEY(CourseDepartment,CourseNumber),
    FOREIGN KEY(CourseDepartment) REFERENCES Department(Name)
);
CREATE TABLE CanTeach (
    SSN CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Department varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CourseNum varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CanTeach_pk PRIMARY KEY(SSN,Department,CourseNum),
    FOREIGN KEY(SSN,Department) REFERENCES WorksFor(SSN,DepName),
    FOREIGN KEY(Department,CourseNum) REFERENCES Course(CourseDepartment,CourseNumber)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this runs in MySQL as in Oracle 18c

So you must have somewhere a typo in your code

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Department (
>     Name varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
> );
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Person (
>     SSN CHAR(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
>     LastName varchar(255),
>     FirstName varchar(255)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Professor (
>     SSN CHAR(9),
>     PRIMARY KEY(SSN),
>     FOREIGN KEY (SSN) REFERENCES Person(SSN)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE WorksFOR (
>     SSN CHAR(9),
>     Salary float NOT NULL,
>     DepName varchar(255),
>     CONSTRAINT WorksFor_Salary CHECK (Salary>=0),
>     CONSTRAINT WorksFor_pk PRIMARY KEY(SSN,DepName),
>     CONSTRAINT WorksFor_ssn_fk FOREIGN KEY(SSN) REFERENCES Professor(SSN),
>     CONSTRAINT WorksFor_dep_fk FOREIGN KEY(DepName) REFERENCES Department(Name)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Course (
>     CourseDepartment varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     CourseNumber varchar(8) NOT NULL,
>     CONSTRAINT Course_pk PRIMARY KEY(CourseDepartment,CourseNumber),
>     FOREIGN KEY(CourseDepartment) REFERENCES Department(Name)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE CanTeach (
>     SSN CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
>     Department varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     CourseNum varchar(8) NOT NULL,
>     CONSTRAINT CanTeach_pk PRIMARY KEY(SSN,Department,CourseNum),
>     FOREIGN KEY(SSN,Department) REFERENCES WorksFOR(SSN,DepName),
>     FOREIGN KEY(Department,CourseNum) REFERENCES Course(CourseDepartment,CourseNumber)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f53263dc5305c2e676bad5e38444deb)*